# How to use calculate two times using DAX in powerbi?

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I want to count a row with specific value as identifier.
I use calculate to calculate the row, but I can only use function "CALCULATE" one time, I can not use it in another column, and return this error

```
A circular dependency was detected:
```

Here is my table looks like:
[image]

I need to count the Total by calculate Max, Min, Target, Value row if has "V", the total supposed to be, 2,2,3,3,1,2 in sequence.

this is what i've tried.

```
CALCULATE(COUNT('Log'[Max]) + COUNT('Log'[Min) + COUNT('Log'[Target)+ COUNT('Log'[Value))
```

Anyone can help  to give advice. Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you have a key column or column that identifies a unique row.

Comment: no, i don'tm have

Comment: You have a circular dependency because of row context. It is impossible to advise further with so little information. Can  you upload a .pbix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myColumn =
VAR t = "V"
VAR myMax = IF ( [Max] = t, 1, 0 )
VAR myMin = IF ( [Min] = t, 1, 0 )
VAR myVal = IF ( [Value] = t, 1, 0 )
VAR myTar = IF ( [Target] = t, 1, 0 )
RETURN 
    myMax + myMin + myVal + myTar
```